# Can we use RabbitMQ for Distributed Transaction in microservice and how we can identify response for perticuler request

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, saga

Used Technologies: SpringBOOT,RabbitMQ

Let say we have two microservices **service1s** and **service2**,and both inter commiunicate asynchronous way using choreography pattern(SAGA).

request ----> service1(publisher) ---->RabbitMQ(Message Broker)---->service2(consumer)

Once **service2** do the process and again response push in RabbitMQ as follows

service2(publisher)--->RabbitMQ----->Service1(consumer)

So my question is how we attached to request to response (coming from service2). how we can identify one single transaction or transactionId.Is that possible or if not what is the solution for this ,some one help me on this.

Comment: Don't use choreography for SAGAs. For any nontrivial use case, it becomes practically impossible to operate and maintain. Use orchestration.

Comment: Actually  choreography for SAGAs also we can track transactionId both  way.just need to push Unique ID (OrderID/TransactionID) to RabbitMQ from service1,again service2 also can do the same thing .No need to go with orchestration.@MaximFateev

Comment: Tracking id is trivial. Dealing with all failure edge cases, especially if you have conditional logic execution on the happy path quickly becomes unsustainable. I would recommend comparing the resulting code of both approaches. Look at the Saga using orchestration: https://github.com/temporalio/samples-java/blob/main/core/src/main/java/io/temporal/samples/bookingsaga/TripBookingWorkflowImpl.java

Answer (score 0):

You can get proper idea from this video,Only different is here used kafka instead of RabbitMQ

[First Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOen1-pQLZg&t=517s)
[Continuing Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O5iJ7PKUhs)